# Javascript and jQuery not working in htdocs folders of xampp

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So I've created a website using HTML,CSS and Javascript and saved it on the desktop. I then created a local server using xampp. I placed this html file in the htdocs folder of xampp. The file is named "foodlist.html". Whenever I try opening this fine in the webbrowser as localhost/foodlist.html, the jQuery and Javascript contents of the file fail to display. Here is a part of the code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script id="javascript" src="file:///C|/Users/Akshat/Desktop/Project/JS-jQuery/addnremove.js"></script>
```

How can I make the javascript and jquery code work each time I open the file on the browser with the /localhost?

Comment: You need to convert the path of `addnremove.js` to a URL. The directory path that you have will most likely not work. Something like `http://localhost/path/to/addnremove.js`

Comment: Additionally, if the html and the JS file are in the same directory, then you should be able to specify the file name in src attribute of script tag. It is probably a good idea to create a proper directory structure for your project with directories for css/js and images etc. This along with proper configuration file will make your code/project more portable when you move it to a different server or to a different location on same server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `file:///C|/Users/Akshat/Desktop/Project/JS-jQuery/addnremove.js` is not a valid address, such kind of linking even with a right address will not work for security reason..

For it to work, e.g. your XAMPP directory is *"C:\xampp"*, you can copy the *"C:\Users\Akshat\Desktop\Project\JS-jQuery"* folder into *"C:\xampp\htdocs"* folder and link your *"addnremove.js"* file this way:

```
<script id="javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1/JS-jQuery/addnremove.js"></script>
```

You can even change the `http://127.0.0.1/` address with `http://localhost/`.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like "file:///C|/Users/Akshat/Desktop/Project/JS-jQuery/addnremove.js" is not a proper link to a file. try putting this file relative to your html like you did with main.css

Comment: Like I said, the whole file is just a copy of the original file saved on the desktop. It's working perfectly fine there.

Comment: It is a good practice to keep everything realtive to the html unless it is on an external cdn. You should move it to the same directory or a sub directory of your html folder